# mysql error error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am associating my user_id to id on the users table. When I send my form I get this error. I have looked around but haven't found a specific answer to my case. I am expecting the user_id to associate with the id on users table. Edit to the question, I added the forms.

```html
$attributes = $project; 
  $getAll = $attributes;
  $getAll['user_id'] = auth()->id();
        //    Patient Form send to database
  $attributes = Project::create(request([
              
             'first_name',
             'last_name',
             'date_wanted',       
             'phone_me',
             'phone_num',
             'user_id'
             
         
         ]));

      return redirect ('/smiledesign/success');
    }
```

//forms to be sent

```
<form method="POST" action="/store" id="form">

  <label for=" "> First Name :  <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
  </label>

<br>
<br>
  <label for=" "> Last Name :  <input type="text" name="last_name" required>
        </label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for=" ">Date Wanted :  <input type="date" name="date_wanted" id="datepicker" required   >
  </label>
  <br>
  <br>

  <label for=" yes"> Phone Me concerning this case:<input type="checkbox" name="phone_me" id="yes"  /></label>
  <label for="yes"> Yes</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone_num" id="phone-num" style="display:none;" />

  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Publish" id="submit">

</form>
```

// My model
    class Project extends Model
    {

```
// protec only specified data
protected $fillable = [
'first_name',
'last_name',
'date_wanted',
'concerns',
'phone_me',
'phone_num',
'user_id'

];

// Patient Form send to database
Project::create(request([

'first_name',
'last_name',
'date_wanted',
'concerns',
'phone_me',
'phone_num',
'user_id'
]));


{ 
// Patient Form validate
request()->validate([
'first_name'=> ['required', 'min:3'],
'last_name'=> ['required', 'min:3'],
'date_wanted'=> 'required',
]);


//Project database table

public function up(){
Schema::create('project', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('date_wanted');
            $table->string('phone_me')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone_num')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

}

// Users database Table

  {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

Comment: In which order are your migrations firing? Because if project is created before users then the error makes sense. Show us your form and controller and split your code from your each other to make it easier to dissect.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about splitting the code. I have done it with comments and is readable. The user creates an account before sending the form so how is the form created before the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by merging using the array_merge

````html
Project::create(array_merge(request([

'first_name',
'last_name',
'date_wanted',
'concerns',
'phone_me',
'phone_num',
'user_id'
]),
['user_id' => auth()->id(),
]));```
````